# Holographic Degrees of Freedom

Tags: degrees-of-freedom, holographic-principle, de-sitter-spacetime

What does it mean when one says "holographic degrees of freedom" in dS space? As Susskind does in his recent papers, the latest [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.01322) (page 18).

Comment: Are you familiar with the holographic principle in the context of quantum gravity?

Comment: Yes, I do. (Sorry if the question was brief.)

Comment: @AayushVerma please edit the question to include what you are already familiar with so as to provide relevant context

Comment: Here's a recent review that addresses holographic degrees of freedom: [Quantum Information in Holographic Duality](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.09188).